# CakePHP and Bootstrap conflicting? CakePHP fetch renders over Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

So this is a bit of a strange one. I'm using CakePHP as my base, combined with Bootstrap as the template system. I've got a nav bar as the header and it worked up until I started rendering content using

```
<?PHP echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
```

If the nav bar is minimized and the expanded version stretches over the content, the content produced by Fetch renders on top of the expanded menu bar. I've tried z-index but it does not seem to have any effect. I first saw this on a page-less view with the error but dismissed it, however after I created a registration page, it showed up again:

[image: CakePHP and Bootstrap Issue]

I'm not too sure what to make of this, and cannot seem to get the positioning correct at all. I'll post the Navbar if I need to, but it's basically a standard nav with drop-downs using default Bootstrap.

Comment: As an additional note, it works just fine if it isn't minimized, but once it is, it breaks as above.

Answer (score -1):

Okay... problem fixed. It was due to the divs I had set up to contain the nav.